# Upgraded server getting error in django

Tags: python, django

I am in a virtual enviornment `(env):~ ./manage.py runserver` gives me this:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

And then the internal server error is this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.clickjacking: "No module named clickjacking"
 mod_wsgi (pid=1209): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/momnet/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.clickjacking: "No module named clickjacking"
```

Site is offline. Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: What version of Django did you have and what version are you running now?

Comment: It doesn't even look like it is installed anymore. `(env):~/code$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> `

Comment: "Well, there's your problem!" -- Adam Savage

Comment: But then it looks like it is install, but not virtually... `(env):~$ sudo !!
sudo pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`